# How to map an array of objects to different components props in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects in `experiment.js` like this:

```js
[
 { fullName: 'vocab Experiment', shortName: 'vocab', ......},
 { fullName: 'mind Experiment', shortName: 'mind', ......},
 { fullName: 'whichenglish Experiment', shortName: 'whichenglish', ......},
];
```

It could be less than or more than 3 objects in the experiments array.

How can I map that array of objects to different components as props like:

```js
import experiments from './experiment.js';

// ......

{experiments.map(e => (
              <Vocab
                id={e.shortName}
                title={e.fullName}
                duration={e.duration}
                post={e.tagline}
                img={require('../assets/images/quiz/Vocab.png')}
                key={e.shortName}
              />
              {/* TODO */}
              <Mind />
              <WhichEnglish />
            ))}
```

Comment: You are already passing props to `Vocab`. What is the issue here?

Comment: @palaѕн So I want to pass the first object in the array to <Vocab />, second object to the <Mind />, third object to the <WhichEnglish />

Comment: ok, so will always have max 3 objects in the `experiments` array or it can be less then that also?

Comment: @rui Do you want <Vocab {{... experiments[0]}} /> < Mind {{... experiments[1]}}/> < WhichEnglish {{... experiments[2]}}/>?

Comment: @palaѕн It could be less than 3 objects or more than 3 objects in the experiments array.

Comment: @LongNguyen Well I tried that, just wanna know if there's a way to map the objects in the array to the correct component (eg. the first object in the array is about vocab experiment, so it has to be mapped into `<Vocab />` component).

Comment: At this point you aren't really mapping each element of an array to the same JSX, sounds like you want each element to be rendered into different components.

Comment: You could add a `switch(e.shortName)` inside `map`. And then return based on the value: `case 'vocab': return <Vocab .. />; break; case 'mind': <Mind />` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

```
[
 { fullName: 'vocab Experiment', shortName: 'vocab', ......},
 { fullName: 'mind Experiment', shortName: 'mind', ......},
 { fullName: 'whichenglish Experiment', shortName: 'whichenglish', ......},
];
```

Seeing as there can be any amount of objects in the list, I would use an if-statement as follows:

```
{experiments.map(e => {
    if (e.shortName === 'vocab') {
        return (<Vocab
                 id={e.shortName}
                 title={e.fullName}
                 duration={e.duration}
                 post={e.tagline}
                 img={require('../assets/images/quiz/Vocab.png')}
                 key={e.shortName}
                />)
   } else if (e.shortName === 'mind') {
         return <Mind ... />
   } else if (e.shortName === 'whichenglish') {
         return <WhichEnglish ... />
   } else return null; // keep react happy
})}
```

Comment: Since mapping you may want to return null in the final implicit else so react remains happy.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use array [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method for this purpose and get exact object for each experiment based on `shortName` like:

```
const vocabProps = experiments.find(x => x.shortName === 'vocab') || {};
const mindProps = experiments.find(x => x.shortName === 'mind') || {};
const whichenglishProps = experiments.find(x => x.shortName === 'whichenglish') || {};
```

and just use spread syntax on the props like:

```
<Vocab {...vocabProps} />
<Mind {...mindProps} />
<WhichEnglish {...whichenglishProps} />
```

Or like this, if you want to pass additional props like `img` to the component.

```
<Vocab data={vocabProps} img={require('...')}/>
<Mind data={mindProps} />
<WhichEnglish data={whichenglishProps} />
```

Comment: I like the use of `find`, but I don't know about the spread because the props don't exactly match the properties in the object

Comment: In that case, I think using it like `<Vocab data={vocabProps} />` should work. and OP can also pass additional props if he wants. What do you think?

Comment: Also OP said the array could have more than 3 objects.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to render each array element to a *different* component you can't really use array::map, as that is more for mapping arrays to the same component.

Given experiments array

```
const experiments = [
  { fullName: 'vocab Experiment', shortName: 'vocab', ......},
  { fullName: 'mind Experiment', shortName: 'mind', ......},
  { fullName: 'whichenglish Experiment', shortName: 'whichenglish', ......},
];
```

You can use array destructuring to save each element into named variables

```
const [vocab, mind, whichEnglish] = experiments;
```

Then spread each into the appropriate component

```
<Vocab
  id={vocab.shortName}
  title={vocab.fullName}
  duration={vocab.duration}
  post={vocab.tagline}
  img={require('../assets/images/quiz/Vocab.png')}
/>
<Mind
  id={mind.shortName}
  title={mind.fullName}
  duration={mind.duration}
  post={mind.tagline}
  img={...}
/>
<WhichEnglish
  id={whichEnglish.shortName}
  title={whichEnglish.fullName}
  duration={whichEnglish.duration}
  post={whichEnglish.tagline}
  img={...}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you are looking for?

```
const ComponentByType = {
  vocab: Vocab,
  mind: Mind,
  whichEnglish: WhichEnglish
}

//...
{experiments.map(e => {
  const type = someHowToGetType(e)
  const Component = ComponentByType[type]
  return (<Component key={e.shortName} {{...e}}/>)
})}
```